# Filter nested objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection of docs like

```
{'id':1, 'score': 1, created_at: ISODate(...)}
{'id':1, 'score': 2, created_at: ISODate(...)}
{'id':2, 'score': 1, created_at: ISODate(...)}
{'id':2, 'score': 20, created_at: ISODate(...)}
```

etc.

Does anyone know how to find docs that were created within the past 24hrs where the difference of the `score` value between the two most recent docs of the same `id` is less than 5?

So far I can only find all docs created within the past 24hrs:

```
[{
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        score: 1,
        created_at: 1
    }
}, {
    $match: {
        $expr: {
            $gte: [
                '$created_at',
                {
                    $subtract: [
                        '$$NOW',
                        86400000
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}]
```

Any advice appreciated.

Edit: By the two most recent docs, the oldest of the two can be created more than 24hrs ago. So the most recent doc would be created within the past 24hrs, but the oldest doc could be created over 24hrs ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: {$expr: {$gte: ["$created_at", {$subtract: ["$$NOW", 86400000]}]}}},
  {$sort: {created_at: -1}},
  {$group: {_id: "$id", data: {$push: "$$ROOT"}}},
  {$project: {pair: {$slice: ["$data", 0, 2]}, scores: {$slice: ["$data.score", 0, 2]}}},
  {$match: {$expr: {
        $lte: [{$abs: {$subtract: [{$first: "$scores"}, {$last: "$scores"}]}}, 5]
  }}},
  {$unset: "scores"}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/x6aVdkiAyu0)

**EDIT**:
according to you comment, one option is:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "$id",
      sortBy: {created_at: -1},
      output: {data: {$push: "$$ROOT", window: {documents: ["current", 1]}}}
  }},
  {$group: {
      _id: "$id",
      created_at: {$first: "$created_at"},
      pair: {$first: "$data"}
  }},
  {$match: {$expr: {$and: [
          {$gte: ["$created_at", {$dateAdd: {startDate: "$$NOW", unit: "day", amount: -1}},
          {$eq: [{$size: "$pair"}, 2]},
          {$lte: [{$abs: {$subtract: [{$first: "$pair.score"},
                    {$last: "$pair.score"}]}}, 5]}
  ]}}},
  {$project: {_id: 0, pair: 1}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mtTu4UxbOZ8)

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I should have been clearer in my question. By the two most recent docs, the oldest of the two can be created more than 24hrs ago. So the most recent doc would be created within the past 24hrs, but the oldest doc could be created any time.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly you can try this query:

- First the `$match` as you have to get documents since a day ago.
- Then `$sort` by the date to ensure the most recent are on top.
- `$group` by the `id`, and how the most recent were on top, using `$push` will be the two first elements in the array.
- So now you only need to `$sum` these two values.
- And filter again with these one that are less than (`$lt`) 5.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $gte: [
          "$created_at",
          {
            $subtract: [
              "$$NOW",
              86400000
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "created_at": -1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$id",
      "score": {
        "$push": "$score"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "score": {
        "$sum": {
          "$firstN": {
            "n": 2,
            "input": "$score"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "score": {
        "$lt": 5
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5qIOXYB7N6k)

Edit: [$firstN](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/firstN/) is new in version 5.2. Other way you can use `$slice` in [this way](https://mongoplayground.net/p/wweAAaeJe17).

Comment: Thanks. Sorry I should have been clearer in my question. By the two most recent docs, the oldest of the two can be created more than 24hrs ago. So the most recent doc would be created within the past 24hrs, but the oldest doc could be created any time. This makes me think the `sort` may need to move elsewhere.